# Docker-Compose mount on Windows Server 2016 TP4

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows

I created a test docker container on Windows Server 2016 TP4 with the following command:

```
docker run --name testdemo -it -v C:/Build:C:/Build windowsservercore cmd
```

I see the mounted directory and it works well.

I would like to do the same thing with **docker-compose** in my Windows Server 2016 TP4 environment. I created the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
testdemo:
    image: windowsservercore
    volumes:
        - C:/Build:C:/Build
```

When I run the **docker-compose up** command, I get this error:

```
> ERROR: for testdemo  Invalid volume spec "C": volumeinvalid: Invalid
> volume specification: 'C' Attaching to
```

My question is, how can I mount a Windows host to Windows Container with docker compose? There is a different syntax, what I used in docker run command?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they fixed it in 1.9.0-rc1

https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.9.0-rc1

Bug Fixes

....

- Fixed an issue with Windows paths being incorrectly converted when
  using Docker on Windows Server.

....

Give it a try